# Screenshot non-rectangular extended desktop

Tags: ubuntu, multi-monitor, screenshot

I have just added a second (larger) monitor to my Ubuntu box, when I take a multi-screen screenshot with (eg) `scrot` or `xfce4-screenshooter` I get garbage in the corner which is normally not seen:

[image: Screenshot showing garbage in corner]

Note the scrambled, garbage from a previously viewed webpage.

Desktop uses Openbox, Nitrogen and LXpanel.
This isn't (or shouldn't be, I haven't tested Debian) specific to Ubuntu.

**How can I take a screenshot without corner garbage?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maim has the ability to create localized masking (it was built to replace scrot for the reasons you describe as well as others).

[maim](https://github.com/naelstrof/maim)